# Joomla expired article

Tags: joomla, article, content-expiration

I have a list of articles in Joomla, these are events and are ordered in the front-end on date (from old to new). I filled in "finish publishing" as the date when the event ends. I understand that when the finish publishing date is reached, the article gets expired and thus is not visible in the front-end. So far so good, old events are not visible anymore.

However, what I want is to have a module "past events" in which it shows the last events that happened, at the bottom of the screen. I have looked at archived articles but that gives me a link per month, and when I click on the month it gives me a blank page (?). I have tested and apparently, because a "finish publishing date" is still present this module doesn't work probably.

I have looked at the article category module with the option of filtering the date range on a relative date, but because the events are expired (unpublished?) they don't show up either.

Now my question is, is it even possible to have a list of expired articles from a certain category, without the whole archive function (because I don't see the added value of that)? How can I just show a list of events, ordered on date in a box called "upcoming events", and if the event is over, move it to another box called "past events"?

Answer (score 0):

You need an **archive plugin** to complete your task.

The archive plugin will check all expired articles and move them to archive with new expiration settings. Then you could publish your past articles with **Archived Articles** module.

A list of available plugins is under: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/archive

Comment: I have already tried AutoArchive. I want to refrain from moving my article across categories because I'm using a different article manager plugin than the general one from Joomla, one where I can define add input fields from an article per category.

Also, if I archive the articles I will end up with a link of the month instead of a list of articles when using Archived Articles module, so that module is not an option.

Comment: I see.. Even if you find a module that would display expired articles (with db query customization) you have to change joomla core files to display item page of an expired article so I don't think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Even if I use the archive module, I will end up with a list of months, instead of a list of articles. I haven't found a plugin that is able to display expired articles and I'd rather not change joomla core files. I can understand that moving to another category, changing the expiration date and showing the articles from this category with a module could be an option, but I'm afraid I cannot move my articles accross categories as I explained before.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3 you usually need to create a Guest user group and Guest access level.

Set Guest user group parent to publish.

Set Guest access level to Guest User Group.

In the options of user component set the Guest User Group to Guest.

Comment: We could use some more problem solvers at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Come join us.